# Form to post variables for newsletter signup

Tags: html, forms, variables, newsletter, subscribe

I'm new to html and forms and want to understand how form fields get submitted and posted to a newsletter signup url.

This is the code I have so far.  When someone fills out the form and submits it, will the form action post the name and email to the url and subscribe the user to the newsletter? or do I need some kind of processing file as well?

`<FORM action="http://example.com?fname=<firstname>&email=<email>&redirecturl=abcthankyou" method="post">
    <p>
    <LABEL for="firstname">First name </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><p />
     <LABEL for="email">Email </LABEL><br />
              <INPUT type="text" id="email"><p />
      <INPUT type="submit" value="Subscribe"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </p>
 </FORM>`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: yes, you need some scripting language what process your request, like php, asp, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your form. You want it to look like this with your extra bits:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <input type="text" name="email">
</form>
```

The form will then call your action page and any inputs with `name` set will be passed as `$_POST` variables as set in your `method`. You may want to look at - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response.  I will change the form to look like your example and refer to the link you supplied.  When you say they will be passed as $_POST variables as set in the method are you referring to a PHP file or some other scripting as mentioned in the previous answer?

Comment: No, the method of the form and then PHP does it's magic and supplies your input fields as variables in your next script

Comment: ok .. so I DO need a PHP processing file? Sorry that I find this all so confusing.. I think I need to find someone to walk me through step by step lol

Comment: Yes. Your html form should call a PHP file that does something with the inputs from that form such as logging a user in and then another html page should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the user submits(clicks on the form input of type submit), whatever is entered in the form is packed and sent to the url mentioned in the 'action' attribute of your form. The method in which the data is sent is what we mention in the 'method' attribute. It is usually 'GET' or 'POST'.

Now, the data that is sent is in the form of key-value pairs. To make it simpler, say the user enters username and password in a login form. Then the data sent are

```
username => value_of_username_field
password => value_of_password_field
```

'username' is the key for value_of_username_field.

So if you want to use these values, and do actions like mailing them, you'll need server side scripting languages, preferably PHP.

Comment: For further info, use this link [http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/form-handler/](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/form-handler/)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, as you can see, I have no idea about forms let alone PHP or any server side scripting languages :) So this scripting is related to the method 'POST'?

Comment: My answer is the general case with form handling. the link talks about using POST method.